# C# treeview of SQL data

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, treeview

I have a SQL table looking like this:

```
orderID       customerName        orderDate          valueTotal
================================================================
   1             JohnA            01/02/2013            100
   2             AmandaF          01/02/2013            140
   3             JohnA            05/03/2013             58
   4             FredM            05/03/2013            200
```

And I want to order this information on a `treeView` by either `orderDate` or `customerName`, depending on user settings so that it looks like this if ordered by customerName:

```
JohnA
    01/02/2013
    05/03/2013
AmandaF
    01/02/2013
FredM
     05/03/2013
```

Or like this if ordered by orderDate:

```
01/02/2013
    JohnA
    AmandaF
05/03/2013
    JohnA
    FredM
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

**EDIT:**
I'm using windows forms

Comment: How do you retrieve your data? Do you use Entity Foundation or ADO.Net? How is your data stored inside your program?

Comment: Sort in the correct order by query, then it should be easy to build the tree in code when you can make assumptions about the data's structure.

Comment: @DavidS., I think it's not so much about sorting as it is about grouping. At least that's what I understand from the question.

Comment: It is more about grouping that sorting, that's right. The way I see it is that loading each of the tiers on demand would probably make more sense and make for a more responsive UI. That way I'd have to do a lot more selects from the DB, but the selects would be very simple. ie: Select unique orderDate and then when a user expands a date I'd do a Select unique customerName where orderDate = <currentlySelectedDate>

Comment: That's why I asked about how the data is internally stored. You could load it all in one data base access and then just make use of the `GroupBy()` extension method. You could afterwards iterate the result and add the groups to your subtree.

Comment: I'm using ADO.Net. Currently I'm not really storing anything in the program yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up creating two functions to perform this in a more dynamic and scalable way.

```
    public static TreeNodeCollection SqlToTreeNodeHierarchy(this SqlDataReader dataReader, TreeNode parent)
    {
        // create a parent TreeNode if we don't have one, so we can anchor the new TreeNodes to it
        // I think this will work better than a list since we might be given a real parent..
        if (parent == null)
        {
            parent = new TreeNode("topNode");
        }

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            //at the beginning of each row, reset the parent
            var parentNode = parent;

            for (var i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                // Adds a new TreeNode as a child of parentNode if it doesn't already exist
                // at this level, else it will return the existing TreeNode and save 
                // it onto parentNode. This way, subsequent TreeNodes will always be a child 
                // of this one, until a new row begins and the parent TreeNode is reset.
                parentNode = AddUniqueNode(dataReader[i].ToString(), parentNode);
            }
        }

        return parent.Nodes;
    }

    public static TreeNode AddUniqueNode(string text, TreeNode parentNode)
    {
        // if parentNode is null, create new treeNode and return it
        if (parentNode == null)
        {
            return new TreeNode {Name = text, Text = text};
        }

        // if parentNode is not null, do a find for child nodes at this level containing the key
        // we're after (text and name have the same value) and return the first one it finds
        foreach (var childNode in parentNode.Nodes.Find(text, false))
        {
            return childNode;
        }

        // Node does not yet exist, so just add a new node to the parentNode and return that
        return parentNode.Nodes.Add(text, text);
    }
```

Then I just need to call the functions as follows:

```
using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    sqlConn.Open();

    const string query = "SELECT orderDate, customerName from MAIN";

    using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn))
    {
        using (var sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var treeNodeCollection = sqlDataReader.SqlToTreeNodeHierarchy(null);

            foreach (TreeNode treeNode in treeNodeCollection)
            {
                nativeTreeView.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way I can make it scale with as many child nodes as I want and it also gives me the flexibility of loading the child nodes only when on expand by doing another SQL query and passing the parent as the TreeNode that was just expanded.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ADO.Net, test this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> groups = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

//set these dynamic
string groupingFieldName = "customerName";
string targetFieldName = "orderDate";


SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    if (!groups.ContainsKey(rdr[groupingFieldName].ToString()))
    {
         groups.Add(rdr[groupingFieldName].ToString(), new List<string>());
    }
    groups[rdr[groupingFieldName].ToString()].Add(rdr[targetFieldName].ToString());
}

//next, iterate the dictionary and populate the treeView
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> group in groups)
{
     //add to treeView
}
```

Please note that this is not tested. You still need to test it.

Comment: I like the idea behind it, but it assumes that I would load all of the treeView nodes at the same time, and if there's quite a few to load it might take quite a long time to process... Wouldn't it make more sense to just load one tier at a time?

Comment: Also it doesn't seem very scalable in the sense that it assumes there's only two tiers, and whilst more code could be added for more tiers it seems like it will become very unmanageable rather quickly once that starts happening.

Comment: @cogumel0, I agree on the scalability part. Hence my request for additional details on the data storing. With the loading part, it's highly debatable. If you do have a lot of tiers, the multiple data requests might, and usualy do, take much longer than the processing. In this case it makes more sense to cache the data localy.